# Throw blank even-numbered/left pages

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to typeset a large document using ReportLab and Python 2.7.

It has a number of sections (about 6 in a 1,000 page document) and I would like each to start on odd-numbered/right-hand page. I have no idea though whether the preceding page will be odd or even and so need the ability to optionally throw an additional blank page before a particular paragraph style (like you sometimes get in manuals where some pages are "intentionally left blank"). Can anyone suggest how this could be done, as the only conditional page break I can find works on the basis of the amount of text on the page not a page number.

I also need to make sure that the blank page is included in the PDF so that double-sided printing works.

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep track of page numbers, then just add a PageBreak or canvas.showPage() command at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the platypus engine within reportlab, you could try overriding the `BaseDocTemplate` class and using the `afterPage` and `beforePage` hooks to keep track of page numbers. Then you can use showPage() whenever you encounter an even page.

For example:

```
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import PageTemplate

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    """Override the BaseDocTemplate class to split even/odd pages"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__pageNum = 1

    def afterPage(self):
        """Called after all flowables have been drawn on a page"""

        # Increment pageNum since the page has been completed
        self.__pageNum += 1

    def beforePage(self):
        """Called before any flowables are drawn on a page"""

        # If the page number is even, force a page break
        if self.__pageNum % 2 == 0:
            self.canv.showPage()
            # Increment pageNum again since we've added a blank page
            self.__pageNum += 1
```

Then you can use the new `MyDocTemplate` class to create your document:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    doc = MyDocTemplate(
        'filename.pdf',
        pagesize=A4,
        rightMargin=.3*inch,
        leftMargin=.3*inch,
        topMargin=.3*inch, 
        bottomMargin=.3*inch
    )

    # Your flowables go here
    elements = []

    # Your PageTemplates go here
    doc.addPageTemplates([])

    doc.build(elements)
```